# Remove empty rows and move content from table to other row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table-bordered" width="100%">

<tr>

<th>Product</th>
<th>Service</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 1</td>
<td>S11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 2</td>
<td>S11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S120</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need: where empty row with product (where product's name is empty) delete this row and move service to up product row and delete current service from up product. Example:

In this table we have `product 1`. I need remove `S11` and paste: `S13` and `S14` in single row.

I need this table on result:

```html
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <table class="table-bordered" width="100%">

    <tr>

    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Service</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>S13, S14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td>S120</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I think, that this we can do with javascript or jquery. I try write this code:

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
 if (!$.trim($(this).text())) $(this).remove();
});
```

But this only remove empty rows..

Comment: Have you considered perhaps the nth of child selector.  Or you might consider retrieving the code for the table as a string and processing each row with regex to remove the extra tags to rewrite the table.  Ideally your data would create the table in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let tr
$('table tr').each(function () {

 if($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().length){
    tr = $(this)
    tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text('')
 }else{
    let td = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(2)')
    td.text(td.text() + ' ' +  $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text())
    $(this).remove()
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table-bordered" width="100%">

<tr>

<th>Product</th>
<th>Service</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 1</td>
<td>S11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 2</td>
<td>S11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S120</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Good working. But can you please and paste commas ? Must be: S13, S14 ..

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var x= 0; x < $("table.table-bordered").children[0].children.length; x++) // loop through all table rows.
    {
      if($("table.table-bordered").children[0].children[x].children[1].outerHTML.indexOf(',') != -1) // if the second td  of the table contains a comma
      {
        var arr = $("table.table-bordered").children[0].children[x].children[1].innerHTML.split(','); // split the array so you make as many rows as needed
        for (var y = 1; y < arr.length; y++) { // loop trough the array
          var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create a new row
          var first = document.createElement('td');
          row.append(first) // create a empty td and add it to the row
          var second = document.createElement('td'); // create another td
          second.append(arr[y]); // append the value (whats after the comma)
          row.append(second); // add it to the row
          $("table.table-bordered > tbody").append(row); // add the row to the table
        }
      };
    }
```

With this i managed to add a row to the table but i didn't have time to add it in the right place but you could look into that yourself.

I hope this helps, but to be honest I think you would be better of changing it in the backend.